# how can i put the second line in the table view cell in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the following code to add the next line in the same same but i am not getting the output.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text= [self.dataArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

where  dataarray1 is the following array.

```
self.dataArray1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sugar :   1 teaspoon", @"salt  :   1 teaspoon",@"sugar  :   1 teaspoon", @"salt  :   1 teaspoon",@"sugar  :   1 teaspoon", @"salt  :   1 teaspoon",@"sugar :   1 teaspoon", @"salt  :   1 teaspoon",nil];
```

how can i add the more content in the same cell of table view.

Comment: Have you use the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle as style for your cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` UITableViewCellStyle? I'm guessing that the style you're using might not support the detail text.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the style of the cell when you init it for it to show the detail text.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)stylereuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

the style you are looking for is `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`